# Medical 837 claims linking mother to newborn

Tags: medical-records

This question is specific to standard 837 medical claims forms. As far as I know, when coding for newborns, the newborn baby gets its own 837 claims form (and does not go on the mothers 837). I'm wondering if there are any linking identifiers between mother and newborn. In other words, a mother comes into a hospital and has a baby. She will get an 837 for pregnancy services and her baby will get its own 837. Is there any way to reliably link the baby to the mother?